# Subclassing QgsMapToolDigitizeFeature

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

How does one subclass `QgsMapToolDigitizeFeature`?

I'm trying to create a map tool in QGIS using Python. The tool will need to draw a polygon (and points and lines) in the same manner that QGIS does natively (including obeying any topological rules). Once the feature is placed I will then provide any attributes necessary for the feature.

I've created a tool for adding points using `QgsMapToolEmitPoint` but can't help but feel that I'm doing a lot of work that is repeated within QGIS its self.

So what is the minimum code required to subclass `QgsMapToolDigitizeFeature` that allows a user to draw a polygon. Just doing:

```
class TestPolygonTool(QgsMapToolDigitizeFeature):

    def __init__(self, canvas, cdw):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.cdw = cdw
        super(TestPolygonTool, self).__init__(self.canvas, self.cdw, QgsMapToolCapture.CaptureNone)

    def activate(self):
        super(TestPolygonTool, self).activate()
```

and then activating via:

```
testTool = TestPolygonTool(iface.mapCanvas(), iface.cadDockWidget())
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(testTool)
```

does not appear to be enough.

And more generally where did you find this information? Nobody seems to talk about doing this.

Comment: I am also struggling with this class. did you get anywhere with it?

Comment: Sorry, should have posted my solution earlier. See below.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working myself.

Something like this:

```
from qgis.gui import (QgsMapToolDigitizeFeature,)

class MvpDrawTool(QgsMapToolDigitizeFeature):
    def __init__(self, canvas, cdw, capture_mode, layer_name):
        self.layer_name = layer_name
        self.capture_mode = capture_mode
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.cdw = cdw

        self.draw_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(self.layer_name)[0]
        if self.draw_layer:
            iface.setActiveLayer(self.draw_layer)
            if not self.draw_layer.isEditable():
                self.draw_layer.startEditing()
            super(MvpDrawTool, self).__init__(self.canvas, self.cdw, self.capture_mode)
    
    def addFeature(self, f):
        if self.draw_layer:
            #Add step to undo history
            self.draw_layer.beginEditCommand("Add feature")
            self.draw_layer.addFeature(f)
            self.draw_layer.triggerRepaint()
            self.draw_layer.endEditCommand()
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Then in your plugin:

Imports:

```
from qgis.gui import (QgsMapToolCapture)
from qgis.utils import iface
```

Wire up a button in your tools init:

```
self.button_management_drawpoly.clicked.connect(self.draw_mvp_polygon)
```

In the tool class somewhere:

```
    def draw_mvp_polygon(self):
        self.current_tool = MvpDrawTool(
            iface.mapCanvas(),
            iface.cadDockWidget(),
            QgsMapToolCapture.CapturePolygon,
            "<layer name>"
        )
        self.current_tool.digitizingCompleted.connect(self.current_tool.addFeature)
        iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.current_tool)
```